# How tell Outlook where image files are?

Tags: html, delphi, outlook, delphi-7

Please bear with me; there's a long story coming up. It's about programatically creating HTML e-mails from Delphi-7, sending them to Outlook, and not showing the pictures in it, so if you don't know anything about that, don't bother reading it all.

I have an application that sends variable-text E-mails, from a Delphi-7 program, to Outlook. I'm using a TMailInfo item, use a template HTML file for layout, replace placeholders with data from the program (%NAME% becomes "Johnson" etc), create a new Outlook message and populate HTMLbody with my result. All of this works fine.

Recently my client sent me a new sample message, asking me if I could change this E-mail to the new layout as he sent me. So I saved the E-mail as html (from Outlook, generating a huge HTML file full of code that is hardly understandable for a non-HTML guru like me)), replaced the static data with my placeholders, and saved it as the new template.

This worked fine except for one thing - the new layout included some local pictures (not available from a public web resource). When original sample mail from outlook, two things were created - a htm file with the html code, named "Subject" AND a folder called "Subject_files", containing the picture files plus a filelist.xml and an mso file.

The generated HTML refers to the pictures as src="subject_files/image001.jpg"> etc.

When I send the HTML to Outlook, it obviously has no idea where the images are - but how do I tell him?

What I tried:

- copying the "subject_files" folder to "My Documents"
- hardcoding the links to the pictures in several formats (i.e.

src="C:/test/subject_files/image001.jpg",

src="C://test/subject_files/image001.jpg",

src="C:\test\subject_files\image001.jpg",

and the like

but both don't work... so my question is really, how do I tell Outlook where to look for image files when programatically creating an HTML message?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Once you the email, the recipient does not have access to your computer, So the images won't show in the email. to send images in an email you can:

**Use aboslute links**

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/header.jpg">
```

**Use embedded images**

Convert your images to BASE64, you can find many web sites online to that like 
 https://www.base64-image.de/ then

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/*base64-generated-string*/" />
```

Comment: A third option is to attach the images to the email with `Content-ID` values assigned to them. And then the HTML can use `<img src="cid:...">` to refer to those attachments.

Comment: Option number two will not work in Outlook - HTML messages are rendered by Word, not Outlook, and it does not understand src="data:image" images.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Remy, the images can be added as regular attachments. You will then need to set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F`) using `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`. The HTML body must use the matching value for the cid attribute  - `<img src="cid:xyz">`, where "xyz" is the value of the  `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property.

Comment: Thanks, but this is so Microsoftic again... needlessly complicated, probably very usefull for edge cases but tedious to figure out in very simple use cases... I'll go for the "publicly hosted" route. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: There is really nothing complicated here - that is how Outlook and all other email clients did this for years and years..